# how to convert several files simultaneously using ffmpeg?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I need to convert many avi files (over 100) to mp4 using ffmpeg. I made a batch file like this, and it works.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "A.avi" -s 320x240 "A.mp4"
ffmpeg.exe -i "B.avi" -s 320x240 "B.mp4"
ffmpeg.exe -i "C.avi" -s 320x240 "C.mp4"
ffmpeg.exe -i "D.avi" -s 320x240 "D.mp4"
...
```

The problem is they occur in sequence, not simultaneously so that it takes too much time. My CPU is 8 core, and 64 bit, 8G Ram, so I guess it would be better to do them as simultaneously as possible. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure ffmpeg isn't multithreaded already?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The console is displaying line by line in a file, and after every line is done, it starts the next file.

Comment: That doesn't mean it isn't multithreaded. The encoder could spawn multiple worker threads per file, which would make parallel processing pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the max number of threads ffmpeg can use with the `-threads` parameter, however this is no guarantee that it uses the cpu fully.

```
ffmpeg -i ... -threads 8 ...
```

If you wan't to run multiple transcode jobs in parallel from your batch script, you could try to start them with the `start` command.
Since you have more than 100 jobs, you might want to seperate them into smaller batch scripts, that you can run in parallel.

Start_all.bat:

```
start batch_1.bat
start batch_2.bat
```

Batch_1.bat

```
ffmpeg -i ...
ffmpeg -i ...
ffmpeg -i ...
```

Batch_2.bat

```
ffmpeg -i ...
ffmpeg -i ...
ffmpeg -i ...
```